# Staying Connected to Splunk Through Python

Tags: python, splunk

I'm trying to run about 300 queries on Splunk through a Python script. The python script typically loses connection because I need to be an authorized user to use Splunk and my authorized session gets dropped. I use the following code to connect:

```
service = client.connect(
  host=HOST,
  port=PORT,
  username=USERNAME,
  password=PASSWORD,
  autologin=True
)
```

The `autologin=True` line allows the bindings to try to re-connect when authentication fails, but even with that, I loose connection.

Is there anyway to ensure I will stay connected to Splunk through Python while this script runs?

Would setting up the splunkrc file fix my issues? http://dev.splunk.com/view/java-sdk/SP-CAAAEDF

Comment: Why are you connecting it to Splunk? Can you output log information to be indexed by Splunk?

Comment: i can not. It's in a very large environment where I don't have access to the log files

Comment: What error do you get when your session drops? You can reconnect on error: `def connect_to_splunk(): return client.connect(...)`, `service = connect_to_splunk()`, `try: do_something(service)`, `except AppropriateException: service = connect_to_splunk()`

Comment: Here's my error: `Autologin succeeded, but there was an auth error on next request. Something is very wrong.`